# Why do I need to cast self to id?

Tags: objective-c, casting, initialization

I have an init method that takes an (id) argument:

```
    -(id) initWithObject:(id) obj;
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
    [[MyClass alloc] initWithObject:self];
```

But XCode is complaining about the argument being a "distinct Objective-C type" (which usually indicates a type mismatch or level of indirection error).

If I explicitly cast self to (id) the warning goes away. In either case the code runs as expected.
Interestingly, on the next line I'm passing self to another method that also takes an id, and that works fine.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something subtle - or is it a peculiarity of the compiler?

I'm not entirely comfortable just casting it until I'm sure of the reasons why it's necessary.

[Edit]

I've been asked to supply more code. Not sure there's much else that's relevant. Here's my actual code that makes the call. Note that it is, itself, within an init method. It's the call to `initWithSource` that's giving the warning:

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
    if( self )
    {
        delegate = nil;
        touchDelegate = [[TBCTouchDelegate alloc] initWithSource:self];
        [touchDelegate.viewWasTappedEvent addTarget: self action:@selector(viewWasTapped:)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here's the init method being called:

```
-(id) initWithSource:(id) sourceObject
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        // Uninteresting initialisation snipped
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You might want to post more code here; nothing's jumping out, but with only two lines to work with, it's hard to say.

Comment: Agree with Ben, but one thing to consider, is the initWithObject method declared?

Comment: Thanks for looking, guys. I've added a bit more code above, for what it's worth.

@Jason: Yes, initWithSource (my actual method name) is declared in the header, and it definitely matches.

Comment: Oh, and to pre-empt your next question - yes I am including that header in the file that makes the call ;-)

Comment: Instead of using your existing project can you create a 'clean' example of it happening? I sometime find the problem when I try to do that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically this means there's multiple `initWithSource:` method names on different classes with conflicting argument types.  Remember, if a variable is typed as `id` the compiler does not know what class it is.  Thus if you call `initWithSource:` on an `id`-typed object and multiple classes have an `initWithSource:` method, the compiler essentially just picks one of the two.  If it picks the "wrong" one, well, you get a "distinct Objective-C type" error.

So why is this happening to you?  I'm not 100% sure, but remember that `+[TBCTouchDelegate alloc]` returns an `id`.  Thus chaining the alloc/init calls is equivalent to this:

```
id o = [TBCTouchDelegate alloc];
touchDelegate = [o initWithSource:self];
```

Hence, you are calling `initWithSource:` on an `id`-typed variable. If there's a conflicting `initWithSource:` method, you could get this compiler error.

Is there a conflicting method?  I checked the system, and the only conflicting one was in `NSAppleScript`:

```
- (id)initWithSource:(NSString *)source;
```

Now `NSAppleScript` *is* part of Foundation, but I noticed this is iPhone code.  So perhaps you only get this error when compiling for the simulator, and not the device?

In any case, if this is your problem, you could get around it by splitting alloc/init onto two different lines:

```
touchDelegate = [TBCTouchDelegate alloc];
touchDelegate = [touchDelegate initWithSource:self];
```

Now, you're calling `initWithSource:` on a fully-typed variable (instead of `id`-typed), so the compiler no longer has to guess which one to pick.  Or you could cast the return from `+alloc`:

```
touchDelegate = [(TBCTouchDelegate *)[TBCTouchDelegate alloc] initWithSource:self];
```

Another solution is to rename `initWithSource:` to avoid the conflict and perhaps make it more descriptive.  You don't say what the class is currently named nor what the "source" is for, so I cannot throw out any possibilities.

Comment: I tried copying your code into my own project, and command-double-clicking on initWithSource. Despite it being an iPhone project, it is indeed trying to reference NSApplescript, as per Dave's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Dave - that was spot on - and clearly explained too!
Fortunately, the word "source" was fairly arbitrary, so I've been able to change it quite readily. The TouchDelegate is a proxy for touches events, and the "source" is the object it is proxying for. I've called it TouchSource now.

Comment: Thanks for the additional confirmation too, Ben, and for taking the time to help.

Comment: This answer is the correct one. It should be marked as 'accpeted'!