# Compiler warning when passing NSError ** as a method parameter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compiler-warnings, compiler-bug

I've been scratching my head about this for the last 4 hours, trying out all kinds of little experiments, but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. Could this be a compiler bug?

Test.m:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL error:(NSError **)error
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) {
        return nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

main.m:

```
NSError *error;

Test *t = [[Test alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/"] error:&error];
```

Here's the compiler warning (from main.m):

> warning: incompatible Objective-C
>   types 'struct NSError **', expected
>   'struct NSDictionary **' when passing
>   argument 2 of
>   'initWithContentsOfURL:error:' from
>   distinct Objective-C type

I'm using the latest versions of Xcode and Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that it's picking up a different instance of the selector, `initWithContentsOfURL:error:` - perhaps the one in [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAppleScript/initWithContentsOfURL:error:). Remember that `[NSObject alloc]` returns an `id`.

Does your code work as expected at runtime?

Try casting the return of `[Test alloc]` to `Test*`.

i.e.

```
Test *t = [(Test*)[Test alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/"] error:&error];
```

Comment: You're correct. Objective-C doesn't like methods with the same signature to have different types (i.e. it doesn't do overloading), so avoid naming two methods the same if they take different parameters.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I had no idea Objective-C could run into these namespace pollution problems. You'd think Apple would have addressed this in Objective-C 2.0...

Comment: Yeah, it's a nasty one. I was bitten by it a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312608/why-do-i-need-to-cast-self-to-id

Comment: Saying ObjC doesn't like methods with the same signature to have different types is like saying C doesn't like passing a `struct *` pointer to a function that takes a `void *` type.  ObjC is just fine with methods with the same signature and different types (ie, different classes using the same selector but different types for the parameters).  It does have a problem when you use `id` as the object type in such cases because it is ambiguous as to "which one you mean"- `id` means it can mean both.  You need to statically type the object- `[(NSRightType *)[NSRightType alloc] init…]`

Comment: I think Graham was probably thinking about trying to overload a method on the same class (which is not the case here).